# Game Loop control

Tags: java, java-3d

i'm having a tremendous difficulty understanding a piece of code that controls a loop of a game... I can't understand the purpose of this while loop "while(unprocessedSeconds > secondsForEachTick)"  and why the FPS counter if inside of that if(tickCounter % 60 ==0) like follows on code:

```
public void run() 
{
    int frames = 0;
    double unprocessedSeconds = 0;
    long previousTime = System.nanoTime();

    double secondsForEachTick = 1/60.0; 


    int tickCount = 0; //RENDER COUNTER
    boolean ticked = false;

    while (running) 
    {
        long currentTime = System.nanoTime();
        long passedTime = currentTime - previousTime;

        previousTime = currentTime;

        unprocessedSeconds = unprocessedSeconds + passedTime / 1000000000.0;

        int count = 0;
        while(unprocessedSeconds > secondsForEachTick)
        {   
            tick();
            count++;
            unprocessedSeconds -= secondsForEachTick; 

            ticked = true;
            tickCount++;

            if(tickCount % 60 == 0){
                System.out.println(frames + " fps");
                previousTime += 1000;
                frames = 0;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Iterações do loop: "+count);

        if(ticked)
        {
            render();
            frames++;
            ticked = false;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `tickCount % 60` Without getting in the code, because of the name and the 60, it smells like minutes/seconds calculations.. (1 min = 60 seconds) - Debug it and you'll better understand it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That inner while cycle ensures that the game update is based on fixed time, rather than frame time. The unprocessed time is getting collected and as soon as it is greater than the time frame for one tick, it calles `tick()`.

The `TickCount` is basically counts the ticks (the tick time is 1/60 sec, so 60 tick/sec), and as soon as it 1 sec elapsed it prints the collected frames (so FPS). Also, `ticked` signals that something may changed in the game, so a new render is required.

Comment: Man, so much thank you! I'm trying to understand it's logic for about 3 days and now I can see it! Great job! Cheers from Brazil!

Answer (score 0):

This loop is used to have constant time in game. So if for some reason you get lag, you will do several logic update and one render. I assume tick() performs some logic operations.

To be more precise. For example, you have bullet, and bullet position need to be updated at 0.1s to do proper collision test. If for some reason delta time grows to 0.4s your bullet will fly through walls. To deal with it you performs several iterations with smaller time step, this loop doing it.

Comment: Thanks for helping buddy, as I'm new on game development I couldn't see that tick() does only logic updates and it was not really a proper rendering operation! Cheers from Brazil!